# full Page Caching on ASP.NET MVC3 with c# and razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, caching

I'm working on large e-Commerce site which is based on ASP.NET MVC3 with C#.I want to do Full Page Caching on all pages like Home page,Categories pages,Product Listing Pages,Product Details pages etc.

But I'm little bit confuse about how to handle Cart,wishlist etc per Customers which is dynamic?

So suggest me how to do Full page Caching? or Is there any suggestion how to get better performance? I'm really concern about site performance because site is contains 1 Lakh products and taking so much time to load.

Now It's time to do very aggressive caching so how to do all these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **Cart, Wishlist etc** are implemented as seperate child actions or partial views, their caching can be disabled. While you can enable the caching using **Cache** attribute, already there in MVC3.

Comment: Yes,Cart,wishlisht etc are implemented as separate child actions and partial view.how can i enable caching in mvc3?

Comment: [OutputCache(Duration = 1200,Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
 like this